# Analysing an s-domain circuit with multiple sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

So I am working on the following circuit:
[image]

I have already worked my initial conditions and the next step is to perform analysis of the charged up circuit. My charged circuit is shown below:
[image]
The charged circuit now has 4 sources. I am confused as to how I can go about analyzing the charged circuit. For some clarity, the dependent current source is 0.9vd and the dependent voltage source is 2it.

Comment: Wouldn't now be a good time to use Kirchoff's current law and sum up all the voltage sources around the loops in the first example?

Comment: Also, you have shown some dependent sources with no dependencies

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have summed the voltages in the first part already. As I have mentioned, I have already done analysis of the circuit with no energy stored in it.

Comment: Can you show that?